# AWS Boto 3- Unable to create tag, instance ID not found - Different region

Tags: python, aws-lambda, boto3

I'm tryng to set tag on instances in multiple regions using Lambda function:

print instance_ids gives me correct id

['i-008a4292a5928c85f']

['i-008a4292a5928c85f', 'i-03253cdbe35bfb1e2']

```
  instance_ids = []
    launch_date = ""
    launched = ""
    launched1 = ""
    ec = boto3.client('ec2')
    ec2_regions = [region['RegionName'] for region in ec.describe_regions()['Regions']]
    for region in ec2_regions:
     ec = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region)
     ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2',region_name=region)
     reservations = ec.describe_instances().get('Reservations', []) 

     for reservation in reservations:
      for instance in reservation['Instances']:
         tags = {}
         for tag in instance['Tags']:
             tags[tag['Key']] = tag['Value']
             if tag['Key'] == 'Name':
               name=tag['Value']
         if not 'Owner' in tags or tags['Owner']=='unknown' or tags['Owner']=='Unknown':
              instance_ids.append(instance['InstanceId'])  
              if not 'TerminateOn' in tags:#, create it
                 print  instance_ids
                 ec2.create_tags(Resources=instance_ids ,Tags=[{'Key':'TerminateOn','Value':date_after_month.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')}])
```

['i-008a4292a5928c85f'] is in different region and lambda creates tag for it:

i-03253cdbe35bfb1e2 is in same region as lambda and tag for that machine is not created although lambda complains it can't find instance for which Tag IS CREATED

```
ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidInstanceID.NotFound) when calling the CreateTags operation: The instance ID 'i-008a4292a5928c85f' does not exist
```

If specifying instance ID manually, no issues

so created to put instance_id instead of list:

```
if not 'TerminateOn' in tags:
                  a = "'" + instance['InstanceId'] + "'"
                  #print a
                  ec2.create_tags(Resources=[a] ,Tags=[{'Key':'TerminateOn','Value':date_after_month.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')}])

but getting The ID ''i-008a4292a5928c85f'' is not valid"
```

Comment: You say the instance `i-008a4292a5928c85f` is in a different region and Lambda creates a tag for it, but that's the ID in the error message. It's really unclear what's your setup and what you're asking.

Comment: yes, it's in the error message,i'm trying to create tags without error for both instances

Answer (score 0):

Works in this way (no idea why it won't take list as parameter), by specifying variable with instance id

```
if not 'Owner' in tags or tags['Owner']=='unknown' or tags['Owner']=='Unknown':
              #ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2',region_name=region)
              instance_ids.append(instance['InstanceId'])  
              if not 'TerminateOn' in tags:

                  ec2.create_tags(Resources=[instance['InstanceId']] ,Tags=[{'Key':'TerminateOn','Value':date_after_month.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')}])
```